# Rails form helper: Radio Button doesn't take css-class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails form helper and want to add a css-class to a radio button input field.

```
            <span class="input-nile">
              <%= f.radio_button :nile_administration, class: 'input__field input__field-nile radio' %>
              <label class="radio-label">Nile Administration</label>
            </span>
```

The output is

```
           <span class="input-nile">
              <input type="radio" value="{:class=>&quot;input__field input__field-nile radio&quot;}" name="user[nile_administration]" id="user_nile_administration_classinput__field_input__field-nile_radio">
              <label class="radio-label">Nile Administration</label>
            </span>
```

I want to achieve that the input tag of type radio get the css class "radio" like the following:

```
            <span class="input-nile">
              <input type="radio" value="" name="user[nile_administration]" class="input__field input__field-nile radio" id="user_nile_administration_classinput__field_input__field-nile_radio">
              <label class="radio-label">Nile Administration</label>
            </span>
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the place of the colon

replace

```
<%= f.radio_button :nile_administration, class: 'input__field input__field-nile radio' %>
```

with

```
<%= f.radio_button :nile_administration , :class => 'input__field input__field-nile radio' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= f.radio_button :nile_administration, '', '', class: 'input__field input__field-nile radio' %>
```

As mentioned in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button), `radio_button` takes its options as the 4th argument:

```
radio_button(object_name, method, tag_value, options = {})
```

Comment: thanks subr00t, you're right but i tried this and i still can't manage to set a css class to this radio button. the output: <input class="input__field input__field-nile radio" type="radio" value="{}" name="nile_administration[{}]" id="nile_administration_{}_">

Comment: @StandardNerd What you mean by setting a css class? You can just edit the `class: 'blablabl'` part to add whatever class you want!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is work for you:

```
<span class="input-nile">
  <%= f.radio_button :nile_administration,"",class: 'input__field input__field-nile radio', id: 'user_nile_administration_classinput__field_input__field-nile_radio'%>
  <label class="radio-label">Nile Administration</label>
</span>
```

Comment: this doesn't work either. the output: <input class="input__field input__field-nile radio" type="radio" value="" checked="checked" name="user[nile_administration]" id="user_nile_administration_">

Comment: I think you want same id of radio button I have made some changes

Answer (score 0):

You can set the custom id, classes, and other attributes for the f.radio_button as follows. Because it only takes 3 arguments. That is why using brackets.

```
 <%= f.radio_button :entity_type, 'practice', { checked: true, id: 'entity_type_practice', class: "custom-control-input entity-radio-button" } %>
```